# VSCode Open a File In a Specific Line Number Using JS

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I added a new button to my VSCode, such that when I click it - it compiles the current folder, and shows dialog boxes using `vscode.window.showInformationMessage`.
Each box shows a compilation error, and has a button in it. Once the user clicks the button - it opens the problematic file in a tab using `vscode.workspace.openTextDocument`. 

I want to make the button to also navigate me to the problematic line in the problematic file.

**My question is:**
Given a number, is it possible to navigate to a specific line number inside a file?

**Sample code of what I achieved so far:**

```
// Bullshit to give some context
const pattern = /(In \w+.jack)/g;
var i = s.search(pattern);
var substring = s.substring(i + 1)
var j = substring.search(pattern);
var s = "bsadsdbla In main.jack (line 55) sqdwqe blasdsd wq qqweq"
let GoToFile = 'Go to File'; 
var k = s.search(/(\w+.jack)/);
var l = s.search(/(.jack)/)
var fileName = s.substring(k, l);

// ---------> This is the important part <----------------
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(s.substring(i, j), GoToFile).then(selection => {
    if (selection === GoToFile) {
        vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(currentDirectory + '\\' + fileName + '.jack')
        .then(document => vscode.window.showTextDocument(document));
    }
});
```

Comment: why don't you add a problem matcher to your task? Use `editor.revealRange()`. If using this you need  closure to pass on the line number to the `then` handler

Comment: @rioV8 How do I use it in my code? I've read its API doc, I don't understand what to do.

Comment: the argument is a `Range`, create it for the correct location and call the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some background:**
As @rioV8 mentioned, `revealRange` was the way to go, but the problem was that I couldn't understand how to use it using the VSCode API, so here @Shahriar Hossain came into the picture. @Shahriar Hossain's code works, however, there was an important declaration missing, and I also had to figure out how to run the code when the user clicks the button.
**This is the full solution:**

```
       vscode.window.showInformationMessage(s.substring(i), GoToFile).then(selection => {
          if (selection === GoToFile) {

            vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(currentDirectory + '\\' + fileName + '.jack')
            .then(document => vscode.window.showTextDocument(document))

            // Whatever code inside this "then" block 
            // will be executed on button click
            .then(x => {
              let m = s.substring(i, j).search(/\(line \d+\)/);
              let subStr = s.substring(m + 6);
              let n = subStr.search(/\)/);
              subStr = subStr.substring(0, n);
              let lineToGo = parseInt(subStr.match(/\d+/));

              // The missing declaration of the activeEditor
              let activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
              let range = activeEditor.document.lineAt(lineToGo - 1).range;
              activeEditor.selection =  new vscode.Selection(range.start, range.end);
              activeEditor.revealRange(range);
            })

          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have some code/regex in place that gives you the line number. Whenever someone clicks your GoToFile method invoke the following code :

```
activeEditor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(lineToGo, lineToGo)];
var range = new vscode.Range(lineToGo, lineToGo);
activeEditor.revealRange(range);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was extremely helpful! I'll post a detailed solution for my problem using your answer.